# Get score and Category for specific user from Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have the following json structure:

```
"Question_Score" : {
    "anna_01" : {
      "categoryID" : "01",
      "categoryName" : "Intelligence",
      "question_Score" : "anna_01",
      "score" : "20",
      "user" : "anna"
    },
    "anna_03" : {
      "categoryID" : "03",
      "categoryName" : "Constitution",
      "question_Score" : "anna_03",
      "score" : "170",
      "user" : "anna"
    },
    "stelios_01" : {
      "categoryID" : "01",
      "categoryName" : "Intelligence",
      "question_Score" : "stelios_01",
      "score" : "230",
      "user" : "stelios"
    },
    "stelios_02" : {
      "categoryID" : "02",
      "categoryName" : "Widsom",
      "question_Score" : "stelios_02",
      "score" : "220",
      "user" : "stelios"
    },
```

I want for currentuser get the categoryID and score. So probably i need to check equality currentuser == user and then get the categoryID and score for this user. As i m new in firebase i find it a little difficult.

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Question_Score");

// Attach a listener to read the data at your profile reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question_Score.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.v("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

I dont know from here how to take the values of CategoryId and score to check equality. I ll apriciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to read the `Question_Score` child nodes that have a specific value for `categoryID`. You can do that with a Firebase Database query on the `categoryID` property:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
questionScoreRef = database.getReference("Question_Score");
Query query = questionScoreRef.orderByChild("categoryID").equalTo("01");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, childSnapshot.getKey()+": "+childSnapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
questionScore.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

This prints the key and `user` value of each child node that has `categoryID` of `"01"`.

Comment: Actually i want to add an if statement like "if category = 01 && score = 100 do... So i need to have this two values for the user. I ll try your solution!